# LInq to SQl problem....Please help

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have the following data

```
ProductId Description cost
12        test        0.0

12        test        8.8

12        test        7.9

27        asdf        9.0
27        asdf        2.0
27        asdf        2.0
```

I want the following result

```
12  test 0.0 / test8.8/test 7.9
27  asdf 9.0/asdf 2.0/ asdf 2.0
```

so far i could only come up with this ..can someone point me in the right direction

Thank you so much

```
var n = from c in query
             group new {c}
             by new
             {
                   c.productid,
                   c.cost,
                   c.prodescription
              }
              into g

              select new{
                                    g.Key.productid,
                                    Products=(g.Key.prodescription) +        g.Key.cost.ToString()),
                                 };
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var groups = from result in query
             group result by new { result.ProductId } into g
             select g;

foreach(var group in groups) {
    Console.Write("{0}: ", group.Key.ProductId);
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join("/", group.Select(p => String.Format("{0}, {1:0.0}", p.Description, p.Cost)).ToArray()));
}
```

Even better would be to provide an implementation of `Product.ToString` along the lines of

```
public override ToString() {
    return String.Format("{0}, {1:0.0}", this.Description, this.Cost);
}
```

and replace the `Console.WriteLine` above by

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join("/", group.Select(p => p.ToString()).ToArray()));
```